# What is the need to pass a container type only when we use a custom comparator in a priority queue?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

My friend was asked in an interview:

"*When we create a priority queue with the default ordering `std::less<T>`, we can just write:*

> std::priority_queue<int> q;

*but when we create one with custom comparator, say, `std::greater<T>`, we have to instead, write:*

> std::priority_queue<int, std::vector, std::greater > q2;

*In your opinion, what is the need to specify the container type `std::vector<int>` in the second case? And, why only in the second case?*"

He was just asked to "make a guess" since he wasn't sure.  The moment I heard it, I realized I had asked it on SO [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350368/finding-top-k-frequent-words) (question 2), but it was unanswered.

Could someone please clarify what the reason is?

Note: Declarations copied from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: check this out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: @Harry, thank you - that is exactly from where I have picked the declarations.

Comment: the template argument for comparator is the third paramter, so in order to specify the third argument all previous default parameters has to be specified which in this case the second parameter (underlying container type).

Comment: @Harry I'm not finding a good duplicate, would have dupe-hammered if I had, so you might want to formalize that into an answer. Shouldn't take much extra.

Comment: @user4581301, thanks, I did not find any, either.

Comment: @Harry, if you convert it into an answer, I would be more than glad to accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: Still can't find a good explanation, but [here is a question with work-arounds to avoid having to specify over and over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694299/explicitly-use-defaults-for-some-parameters-in-class-template-instantiation).